# php error when displaying mysql database table

Tags: php, sql

Every time i try to connect to a database using php, I constantly get this error: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /homepages/12/d441172468/htdocs/Organizer/dashboard/index.php on line 258` How do I fix this? My code is

```
            $email = 'redacted@me.com_classes';

            echo $email;

            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $email");

            $classcount = 1;

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {

              $period = $row['period'];
              $teacher = $row['teacher'];
              $subject = $row['subject'];
              $subjecto = strtolower($subject);
              $subjecto = str_replace(' ', '', $subjecto);
              $grade = $row['grade'];

              echo "<li id='button" . $classcount . "' onclick='" . $subjecto . "(),homework" . $classcount . "()'>" . $classcount . ". " . $subject . "-" . $grade . "</li>\n";

              $classcount += 1;

              }
```

the `$email` variable works fine when I echo it. Line 128 is the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` part

Comment: You are passing `$email` as the table name. Surely you meant something like `"SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE email = '$email'"` after escaping `$email` via `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Are you sure $con is working?

Comment: the value of `$email` is my table name, and I'm sure my `$con` is working

Comment: You _must_ do error checking.  `$result = mysqli_query(...);  if (!$result) echo mysqli_error(); else // ok, do your thing.`

Comment: Your table name is the email address `redacted@me.com_classes` ? Really???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of `$email` really is your table name, you need to quote it as it contains characters (the `@`) that are not allowed in unquoted [table names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html):

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `$email`");
```

Note that you need to quote table- and column names with the backtick in mysql.

Comment: thanks! I quoted it in `'` instead

Comment: @ThomasLai No, if it is a table name, you need backticks, see the manual page I linked to: **The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”)**

Answer (score 0):

A table name is allowed in `ASCII`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

```
    Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:

    ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)

    Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF 

    Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:

    ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F

    Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF 

    ASCII NUL (U+0000) and supplementary characters (U+10000 and higher) are not permitted in quoted or unquoted identifiers.

    Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

    Database, table, and column names cannot end with space characters.

    Before MySQL 5.1.6, database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names.
```

It's weird, are you already manually added table with string `@`. I think that can't be process as table name?

Skip it below

---

Your query is invalid, change your code as example:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 'email' = $email");
```

Change `TABLE_NAME` with a name of table.
Change `email` with  a name of column email on table TABLE_NAME.

You are victim with mysql injection, so not is checked for entites and specialchars too!

If your VALUE $email is TABLE_NAME that should is LIMITED with characters!

Comment: but my table name is the value of `$email`

Comment: Your tables are named by the e-mail?!

Comment: Your TABLE_NAME is TABLE name. Not COLUMN in a TABLE_NAME.

Comment: yeah, its weird but I need it to be